# Counter in entity description ng-admin

Tags: ng-admin

Do you know if it's possible to display the total of results in the description of an enity view in ng-admin ?

Example :
`users.listView()
    .title('Users')
    .description('{{data.total}} Profiles')
    .fields([])`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible since the `listLayoutController` only displays the title but does not fetch the data - that's the `listController`'s job. The total number of items is only available in the datagrid and pagination components.